# Parse.com push notifications VS. Google Cloud messaging for iOS?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Parse Data Core and was planning to use Parse Push notifications for iOS, however Google just announced cloud messaging for iOS @ I/O 2015. I'm a newbie and a little unclear so thought i'd ask. what are the pro's and Con's of using one service over the other? My thought is that since parse counts each push message as a request , GCM might be better since its free with no limit.I think I can trigger GCM in Parse cloud code. Parse notifications also have a large allowable quota under free tier, but not sure if it offers extra simplicity of use over GCM. Also not sure if google requires iOS device to have a linked google account on device to receive a notification.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure about what is gonna be easier to use for you, but GCM doesn't not require a linked Google account for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

visit
 http://www.quora.com/Push-Notifications/Which-is-best-to-use-Amazon-SNS-Google-Cloud-Messaging-or-Parse-Why

it would be helpful,
all you need it's there.

Comment: Please avoid: link only answers. Try to summarize content of the article in the answer. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)